# Compile Error: sizeof() operator in C

Tags: c, arrays

I am not sure if this has been asked before. I tried my best to avoid duplicity.

I was using the sizeof() operator in C.

First I tried this:

```
char *name;
sizeof(name);
```

which returned size as 4 bytes. No issues till now.

Next time I tried this:

```
char name[];
sizeof(name); // I even tried name[]
```

which gave me a Compile error.

Anyone please explain why this occurs?

EDIT: I also tried inputting a string to *name which by far exceeded 4 bytes of length. Yet it was able to handle it properly. However the sizeof(name) still return 4 bytes. Even when the compiler has dynamically allocated enough memory to *name, it still reports occupying 4 bytes. Is this a sizeof() fault?

Comment: char[] has an unknown size. Why do you expect something else than an error for an incomplete type?

Comment: No this is not a fault. `sizeof()` in your case returns the size of `name` a pointer, when you do `sizeof(name)` which should be `4`.

Comment: You should also learn the difference beteeen a string length and the size of an char array. The later is independent from the current content.

Comment: You might be confusing `sizeof()` with `strlen()`.  `Strlen` a library function that count's characters until it finds a terminating nul.  `sizeof` is not a library function,  it is a compile time evaluated unary operator that determines size based on the type of the operand.

Comment: @dennis No, certainly not confusing with `sizeof` with `srlen`. Its just that if I declare them one at a time inside a `struct` , the `sizeof()` counts some default bytes in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char name[];` at file scope is a *tentative definition* of an array. It has *incomplete type*. You do not know its size yet. You cannot do `sizeof` until after the definition has been completed.

Note that this has nothing to do with `char *name;` - arrays and pointers are different.

Re. your EDIT: you are confusing a pointer with the items being pointed to.  `char *name;` takes up 4 bytes, and it points at another `char`. That is what a pointer does: it points at another object. It doesn't necessarily own what it points at. The semantics of a string is a series of `char` objects followed by a null terminator, and `name` should point at the first item of the series.

This all has nothing to do with `sizeof name`, which is the size of *the pointer*, **not** the size of the list of items being pointed at.

Comment: Roger. So sizeof name in first case returns the size taken up by pointer `name` and not to what it points. I understand it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` cannot be used with objects of incomplete array types.

```
char name[];  // name is of an incomplete type
```

C defines *incomplete types* as *types that describe objects but lack
information needed to determine their sizes*.

If you complete the type:

```
char name[];
char name[42];   // type of name is now completed
```

then using `sizeof name` would be valid.

Comment: @Quirk `char b[];` does not allow dynamic allocation of memory. The size must be given at compile time (or it is assumed to be `1` if not given).  BTW don't confuse this with a function parameter `char c[]`, that is completely different

Comment: @Quirk `char *name;` does not declare an object of an array type but an object of the pointer type `char *`. Arrays and pointers are two different beasts.

Comment: @ouah Sorry, but I'm not very familiar with OOP. But thank you, anyway.

Comment: @Quirk The fact that I use the word *object* does not mean it's OOP, C is not an OOP language and in the C terminology an object is a *region of data storage*.

Answer (score 0):

Size of pointer to char is the space in memory required for that type of variable.

Size of an array of chars is number of chars in array. Which is undefined for non initialized array.